# Can I register a fake instance and declare it's return on registration?

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, fakeiteasy

I'm building a testing framework for our Xunit tests. I wanted to create a fake SMTP service that will mimic ours but won't actually work for the tests (For obvious reasons).

Creating a fake instance was easy and worked like a charm. I've added before the modules my the registration of the fakeItEasyObject:

`builder.RegisterInstance(A.Fake<IEmailSender>());`

but now I want it to ALWAYS return true on `EmailSender.Send()` , and I know I can achieve it from the actual unitests with the resolved instance: `A.CallTo(()=>_emailSender.Send(A<Data>.Ignored)).Returns(true);`

I don't want to do it on every test and was wondering if there is a way form to do it on registration. Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: For that you would have to mock your service provider to return a mock IEmailSender when requesting a service of that type.

Comment: @PlamenYordanov   that sounds good, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Is the `IEmailSender` injected as a service or are you manually instantiating an object with that type? And what is the scope of the tests- if they are tests where you resolve dependencies by yourself, then mocking the service provider would not be necessary (and most likely it would be useless to do, anyway). If the tests are broader in scope and dependencies are resolved by your service provider, then it would make sense to mock it.

Comment: it's injected as a service, and when I run the test framework, i register the logic modules and mock the external costly services. My main thought was to program the result of calling the methods in the program where i register the test framework and not where i test, so people could use the testframework effectively without decalring the ```CallTo(()=>...``` on each testfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're repeating your registration all over the place, you could just

```cs
var fake = A.Fake<IEmailSender>();
A.CallTo(() => fake.Send(A<Data>.Ignored))).Returns(true);
builder.RegisterInstance(fake);
```

But I suspect that's not what you're asking.

If you want the default for all your fakes to return `true` on `Send`, you could use FakeItEasy's [Implicit Creation Options](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/implicit-creation-options/). Specifically an `IFakeOptionsBuilder`. Something like

```cs
public class EmailSenderFakeOptionsBuilder : FakeOptionsBuilder<IEmailSender>
{
    protected override void BuildOptions(IFakeOptions<IEmailSender> options)
    {
        options.ConfigureFake(fake =>
        {
            A.CallTo(() => fake.Send(A<Data>.Ignored)).Returns(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Then if there are certain tests where you want to return `false`, you could override at that point.

Comment: pro answer. Thanks.